How to set the default value for choice lookup in screen flow, Once the data got passed fom LWC to flow
In My Screen flow, I have a choice lookup compnent of filtered conditions contacts related to the account and below that there is a custom LWC Component button (New Contact). Upon clicking on that button a new contact is getting cretaed and able to pass newly generated contact id and name from LWC to flow.
I am setting the default value in lookup component as flow.variable name
But it is not automatically populating
I tried by creating resoirce type as record choice set and kept it as default value, still not working
can someone help me on this please
